# IE6: Doesn't load Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps

I'm using the new Google Maps [API v3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html).

It works great with Firefox/Chromo/Safari but the map doesn't load in IE6.

Any ideas why the page loads my map in all browsers except IE6?

Comment: You might try the v3 forum: http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3?pli=1 . If you do get a response there, please post it as an answer here (or a link to it anyway).

Comment: Google maps API [was never meant to run in IE6](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#browsersupport)! Luckily! This internet zombie creature must finally get *coup de grace*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace this code

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map:      map,
    icon:     image,
});
```

to this

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map:      map,
    icon:     image
});
```

(line 509)

Comment: Many, many thanks!  Do you mind explain how you found that bug?

Comment: @mp_: it's a known issue in JScript, Microsoft's implementation of ECMAScript.

Comment: I had to read through it 3 times to find the difference!  Drop the last comma.

Comment: Running the code through an IDE like Intellij IDEA will give you big highlights showing this kind of typo.