# Google map v3 not working on older IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps

Im going a bit crazy here. My google map v3 will work on everything but older versions of IE. Im trying to debug it but with zero success. I load the map into a fancybox which shouldnt have any effect. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/*googlemap*/
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
var myOptions = {
        zoom:14,
        center:myLatlng,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString, maxWidth: 400});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng, map: map, title: hotelName});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', function(){infowindow.open(map, marker)});
};
```

Comment: What versions of IE? Have you tried a test of the map outside of fancybox(ie In a plain html page)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544518/ie6-doesnt-load-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: Thanks Vini-T, ive seen that and tried various bits with no joy. @xanderer, ill try it quickly now and get back to you...but version 8 wont work.

Comment: @xanderer, it wont work as a stand alond page on IE 8 ither.

Comment: @Hatzi What about the map won't work? Is the map not loading? I think getting the map to work on the standalone page is the best first step at this point.

Comment: @xanderer, im gonna give it another shot today on a stand alone page, ill have to strip it down to the basics, ill let you know.

Comment: @Hatzi if you can add more code, I can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a semicolon on this line

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', function(){infowindow.open(map, marker)});
```

After

```
infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

Missing semicolons cause issues in IE

Comment: thanks for your help, yeah i deleted that while trying to debug it, however still no joy